Selecting a competition schedule from a list of teams with alternating home/away
I am trying to create a competition playing schedule given a list of teams. It can have any number of teams n > 2. It needs to create a number of rounds so that each team plays each other once.
It needs to output the competition "round" (starting at 1), a Home team and an Away team.  The home/away status should alternate for teams each round.
The algorithm used could be based on a scheduling algorithm or something similar.
For one more degree of difficulty
It also need to cater for the possibility of an odd number of teams - in which case it will schedule a -bye- with one of the teams each round and this shouldn't count as a home or away match. Each team should only play one -bye- match.
This question goes someway but it doesn't cater for the home and away constraints.
I got as far as being able to generate a list of the team matches, but struggled with incorporating the home/away status and struggled with ordering it and displaying the rounds.
My code so far:
Declare @TeamTable Table 
(
    name varchar(10) 
)

Insert Into @TeamTable 
    Select 'Team A'
    union select 'Team B'
    union select 'Team C'
    union select '-bye-'

Select 
        * 
    From 
        @TeamTable

Select t1.Name as home, t2.Name as away 
    FROM @TeamTable t1 
    INNER JOIN @TeamTable t2 ON t1.name<t2.name

Providing a result of:



home
away




-bye-
Team A


-bye-
Team B


Team A
Team B


-bye-
Team C


Team A
Team C


Team B
Team C



This is good in that is lists all the matches but it is not in any "round" order and poor Team C is playing all Away matches with no home matches.
I would like to see something like:



R
home
away




1
-bye-
Team A


1
Team B
Team C


2
Team A
Team B


2
-bye-
Team C


3
-bye-
Team B


3
Team C
Team A



This has each team playing the same number of home games, the same number of away games and they are all alternating home/away (ignoring byes) as they go through the rounds.
I was about to implement it by using arrays and iterations instead since I have hit a brick wall with trying to do it using SQL. I would prefer an elegant SQL solution if at all possible.

Using window function LAG we can check previous away value and if it equal to current just switch home and away:
WITH seed AS (
    SELECT t1.Name AS home, t2.Name AS away 
    FROM TeamTable t1 
    INNER JOIN TeamTable t2 ON t1.name < t2.name
),
seed1 AS (
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY away) rn,
        LAG(away) OVER (ORDER BY away) prev_away
    FROM seed
) SELECT
    rn,
    CASE WHEN prev_away IS NOT NULL AND away = prev_away THEN away ELSE home END home,
    CASE WHEN prev_away IS NULL OR away != prev_away THEN away ELSE home END away
FROM seed1
ORDER BY rn

Play with the SQL here
Result:



rn
home
away




1
-bye-
Team A


2
-bye-
Team B


3
Team B
Team A


4
-bye-
Team C


5
Team C
Team A


6
Team C
Team B




Thanks for this.  I like the lag() option for ensuring the home/away is alternating.
Now, the round number still needs some work - it isn't quite ordering and grouping the matches into the correct rounds.
